# How to implement Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote code where all names comes from Google API. Now I want to implement search functionality using JavaScript/jQuery. How should I implement search function? That should look the image below

[image]

```
<div id="createGrp" name="Create Label" style="display:none"> 
                <table> <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Label Name: </b>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" maxlength="25" id="lname" name="labelname" onkeyup="return limitText(this, 25), CheckLimit(this, 25, 'vlenName')"/><br></td>
                        <td id="vlenName">
                            <i> 25 Characters left </i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>  
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' id='gleSearchCamp' name='gleSearchCamp' placeholder="Search for campaigns"/>
                            <input type='button' id='entersearch' value='Search' onclick="gleSearch('gleSearchCamp')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                
                </table>
                <br/>
                <table align="left">    <tr> <td>
                            <input type="button" id="lblsave" value="Save"/> 
                            <input type="button" VALUE="Cancel" onclick="hide('createGrp')"/>      
                        </td> </tr>
                </table>            
                <br/><br/> <br/>            
                <table> <tr> 
                        <td><div class="selcheckBox" id="cmplist" name="Select Campaigns">
                                <table style="overflow-y:scroll" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><span class="selectALLWrap"> <input type='checkbox'  id='selectALL' onClick="selectAll(this)"></span><span>Select</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                                            <th class="sortable" id='accountName' align="left" onclick='sortingValues(this);'>Campaign Name</th> 
                                        </tr>                                         
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody style="font-size: 18px;font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Medium';">
                                        <s:forEach items="${campaignDetails}" var="campDetails" >
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class=" "><input type="checkbox" id="campDetails.campaignId" name="campaignName" value="campDetails.campaignName"/> </div></td>
                                                <td>${campDetails.campaignName}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </s:forEach>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>  

                            </div>

                        </td> </tr> </table>
                <br/><br/>                               


            </div>`enter code here`
```

Comment: What you have tried yet in js code?

Comment: I've edited your question - but you really need to try something - anything - before someone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough context of your problem so I'll start with some assumptions, correct me if any of my assumption is not accurate and then I'll be able to help you further.

Assuming that

- You have only small data(upto 100s of items)
- You want a simple keyword match search(as opposed to fuzzy/semantic search)
- You want the solution to be on the client side

In that case, I'd go with following solution based on javascript

First of all, I simplified your html code for readability and added some dummy data. Notice that, I added a html property to search input element `onkeyup="gleSearch()"`. This means that as soon as you type any letter in the searchbox, `gleSearch()` method is called. This method is where we will implement search functionality.

```
<input onkeyup="gleSearch()" type='text' id='gleSearchCamp' name='gleSearchCamp' placeholder="Search for campaigns" />


<ul id="item-list" class="items-list">
  <li id="campaign1" class="item">Foot wear</li>
  <li id="campaign2" class="item">Bags</li>
  <li id="campaign3" class="item">Watch</li>
  <li id="campaign3" class="item">Shoes</li>
</ul>
```

This is how the `gleSearch()` method reads the search query, gets the data from html and then hides the items that don't match the query

```
<script>
function gleSearch() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('gleSearchCamp');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("item-list");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's the [working demo](https://codepen.io/invide/pen/JjWEvxE)